# implementing spring security with ldap and password encoding

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

i have implemented spring security login successfully with ldap and plaintext. now im switching to sha-256 for the password hash in ldap. i have added password-encoder in applicationContext-security.xml. however, i have not been able to authenticate successfully with spring security. i receives "you have entered an invalid username or password!"

here are my codes:

applicationContext-security.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/user/denied" >
            <security:form-login
                    login-page="/login" 
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
                    default-target-url="/admin/user"/>
            <security:logout invalidate-session="true" 
                    logout-success-url="/login" 
                    logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        </security:http>
        <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="uid={0}" user-search-base="ou=Users">
             <security:password-compare>
                 <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
             </security:password-compare>
           </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>

        <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
            <constructor-arg value="ldap://192.168.1.100:389/dc=openLDAP" />
            <property name="userDn" value="cn=admin,dc=openLDAP" />
            <property name="password" value="password" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

login controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   if(session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT" != null) {
      return "redirect:/home";
   }

   if(error) {
      model.put("error", "you have entered an invalid username or password!");
   }
   else {
      model.put("error", "");
   }

   return "login";
}
```

login view:

```
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post" >
   username: <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" />
   password: <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you able to bind with the user and password on your ldap server directly?

Comment: And do you see the password hash in the directory?

Comment: hi in apacheLDAP, i double click the password value and it opens up a password editor. i did two things. 1) in verify password field, i key in my password and bind against plaintext. it works. 2) i tried the same now for sha256 and it returns "The authentication failed. [LDAP error code 49 - invalid credentials"]

Comment: hi, when i save my password, in the value field, it shows SHA-256 hashed password

Comment: Can you try saving the pwd hashed with MD5, SMD5, or SHA and then try again? Those are the three that worked for me out of the box with OpenLDAP.

Comment: i changed the hash algo according to your suggestion and it works on apacheDS. im using apacheDS to connect to openLdap. however, im still not able to login from my spring project after i changed to <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are hashing the passowrd on the client side (spring-security) and then OpenLDAP hashes that string again and then compares the result with the stored password hash. One the two combinations should work:

1. Configure a hashing algorithm in spring-security and store the password hash as plain text password type in OpenLDAP -> The hashed password is sent to your LDAP and compared against the stored hashed password.
2. Do not configure hashing in spring-security and store the password as a hashed password type in OpenLDAP (like you did as per your comment) -> The plain text password is sent to your LDAP, hashed by the LDAP server and then compared against the stored password hash.

I recommend 2) in combination with an SSL encrypted connection to your LDAP server to protect the plain text password in transit. If you go for 2) you can easily enable salting of your password hashes by using the SMD5 password type. 1) has the downside that each client is required to support the chosen hash function.

Comment: hi ralf, solution 1 works. thank you very much. currently im using sha256 in spring security. i read that spring security only supports the following hash algo: plaintext, sha, sha-256, md5 and md4. i would like to use a more secure algo such as sha512. is it possible to implement it in spring security?

Comment: AFAIK you would gain more in terms of security of you'd salt your hashes instead of using a longer hash value variant of the same cryptographic hashing algorithm. If the answer was helpful, could you please up-vote and/or accept the answer as correct?

Comment: thks ralf i think i will do just that